# Azure Log Analytics - new Search REST API

Tags: azure

Azure announced the ability to upgrade Azure Log Analytics workspace recently. It comes with a new query language (https://docs.loganalytics.io/index). But after the upgrade their Search REST API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-log-search-api) isn't working anymore. I wasn't able to find a way to execute new Search Queries via REST. I would imagine that it would be similar to AppInsights API (https://dev.applicationinsights.io/).

It also seems like they have actual API but no documentation as of yet, because Microsoft Flow has ability to integrate and execute Search Queries with the upgraded workspace (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-flow-tutorial).

Any help in pointing on how to execute new Search API via REST is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This should be a more of a question to MS. Post it in comments of learn.microsoft.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation for new REST API wasn't available when this question was posted. Here is the MS response:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/0c044c41-6642-4bb0-9a61-64d6f6b8b042/new-log-analytics-search-rest-api?forum=opinsights